# How will component() and the New Angular Router work together in 1.5?

Tags: angularjs, angular-new-router, angularjs-components

I've read through both proposals individually but am having trouble piecing them together.

So with component() we can set the bindings property to get data from outside of the component.

However, it seems with the new angular router, there is no mechanism to pass the data through these bindings.

Rather, the examples I find, are to inject $routeParams into the component's controller.

But that would limit the reusability of the component! Am I missing something here? How can I set up the router to bind values to the component?